# How to change a string of numbers to a vector in R?

Tags: r, string, vector, character, paste

I have a matrix of this kind:

```
     SeqMAT2
           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
     [1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
     [2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
     [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
     [4,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
```

And I am willing to have, for each line, a vector of integers. For example, for the first line, I would like to have the same result as if I did

```
  a<-c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

I have tried to do:

```
SeqNum <- apply(seqMAT2, 1, function(x)as.vector(paste0(na.omit(x), collapse=",")))
```

But the result is still a character

```
    class(SeqNum[1])
`[1] "character"`
```

Even if I run

```
    as.vector(SeqNum)
class(SeqNum[1])
[1] "character"
```

Do you know how I could transform my character strings into vectors ?

Thank you very much in advance !!

Mélissa

---

Edit: I have found the answer, in case it can help somebody else in the future. Maybe not the most elegant way but at least it works:

```
  `SeqCalls <- apply(seqMAT2, 1, function(x)paste(na.omit(x), collapse=""))#to condensate the columns of the matrix into character strings

SeqNum <- vector(mode="list")#Create a vector to contain the new vectors created

    for (l in 1:length(SeqCalls)){
      SeqNum[l] <- list(unlist(strsplit(SeqCalls[l], split = "")))
    }`
```

Comment: Try `help(as.integer)` or `help(as.numeric)`.  While not an exact duplicate, your question _clearly_ shows that you have not even read the most basic introductions to R, of which there are [dozens available](https://cloud.r-project.org/other-docs.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,
I have tried something like this:

`seqNum <- matrix(0,ncol=1, nrow=m)
for(l in 1:m){
  SeqNum[l,1] <- seqMAT2[l,]
}`

But it keeps telling me that there is an  "incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"
Do you know what is wrong in my formula ?